# Install packages partially in package.json?

Tags: yarnpkg

I need to run a script that requires only a few packages in package.json. But `yarn install` command installs all packages with a lot of time. Is there any solution to install partially I want to install?

Comment: i don't understand, why you don't remove packages you don't need ? if you need to run a script without actually installing project dependencies, you can use yarn global ton install the packages you need once

Comment: because I wanna use cloned repository but it is huge.